# Edit and preview the video in real time on iOS

Tags: ios, video-processing, gpuimage, video-editing

Can I use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) or what real-time editing and preview video on iOS?

I have read the GPUImage's instructions about ["Filtering and re-encoding a movie"](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#filtering-and-re-encoding-a-movie), but it does not seem to preview the video in real time?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a preview of filtered video with following chain (GPUImage):

```
GPUImageMovie -> Any GPUImage Filter -> GPUImageView
```

Comment: So it is! Thank you!